Brew upgrade cmake breaks CMake Tools
On a Mac, I had Visual Studio Code and the CMake Tools extension working comfortably together, and building. Then I did
brew --upgrade

allowing it to update all those outdated formulas that it likes to talk about.
Oops! Now my CMake build is broken.
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /opt/homebrew/bin/cmake --build /Users/ken/vsc/catch/build --config Debug --target all -j 12 --
[build] gmake: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.29.3/bin/cmake: No such file or directory

But I type
% cmake --version
cmake version 3.29.4

Something is remembering an outdated version (3.29.3) of CMake, and not finding it. Where do I go to update this?
I tried
% cmake --fresh -S .

Which ran correctly but didn't fix anything.
Log of the upgrade:
==> Upgrading cmake
  3.29.3 -> 3.29.4 
==> Pouring cmake--3.29.4.arm64_sonoma.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
To install the CMake documentation, run:
  brew install cmake-docs

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d

Emacs Lisp files have been installed to:
  /opt/homebrew/share/emacs/site-lisp/cmake
==> Summary
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.29.4: 3,385 files, 55.5MB
==> Running `brew cleanup cmake`...
Removing: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.29.3... (3,385 files, 55.5MB)
Removing: /Users/ken/Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake_bottle_manifest--3.29.3... (12.3KB)
Removing: /Users/ken/Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake--3.29.3... (16.6MB)


Sounds like you just want to delete your build directory (including all the cmake cache files) and then do a new clean build..

Thanks, @JesperJuhl, but not quite. I deleted the CMakeFiles directory and did a clean configure. After that, cmake --build . in a terminal window succeeds, but F5 still has the problem.  This tells me, as I suspected, that Cmake Tools is caching the outdated path to CMake, and I don't know where to look for that.

The answer, when I found it, took me greatly by surprise. I looked in the Extensions tab of Visual Studio Code, and there discovered that this and several other extensions had a button labeled "Restart extensions”. When I pressed it, the outdated cache was cleared, and everything worked fine.

Further research reveals that I need to ALSO delete the build directory as well as re-starting extensions, to clean this up. Seems to be required in every project directory I possess that uses cmake tools.
